# jasper pdf report generation, status 404 while passing model and view

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jasper-reports, javabeans

I am currently working with Jasper Report. I got an 404 error while running my project. Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/generatePdf.MRCMPU",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView PdfCreation(Model map,ModelAndView modelAndView,ModelMap maps,HttpServletResponse response)
{

     try
     {
        JRDataSource list=new JREmptyDataSource();
        Map<String, Object> paraMap=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        paraMap.put("datasource",list);
        modelAndView=new ModelAndView("masterpdfReport",paraMap);
        return modelAndView;        
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return null;            
     }              
}
```

**Jasper View XML**

```
 <bean id="masterpdfReport"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView" 
  p:url="/WEB-INF/masterpdf.jrxml"  p:reportDataKey="datasource"/>
```

in Spring Servlet xml:-

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

<property name="prefix">
    <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
</property>
<property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
</property>
</bean>
```

When I run my project, status 404 error is occurring. I am using tomcat 7.0.67. Is there anything to add?

Comment: This isn't a JasperReports-specific problem. Also, prefer using the `.jasper` file to the `.jrxml` file as it'll save a compilation step, speed up producing reports, and simplify the Java code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue myself by simply adding a bean, **xmlviewResolver**.
here is the bean :

```
 <bean id="xmlviewResolver"
     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jasperView.xml"/>
```